# Custom short citation merging author-title-volume to one single field

Tags: biblatex, biber, report

How can I make a **custom short citation merging the fields of author-title-volume to a custom field** such as "MRCLC 61:130" instead of "Matuz, Contemporary Literary Criticism, 130." I need this in view of some conventions in my field of study. Please see the example below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[notes,noibid,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,backend=biber,urldate=long]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This is when I first cite the referred author~\autocite[12]{matuz:doody}. 
How can I modify what is presented in the citation when I cite the same author and book a second time?~\autocite[130]{matuz:doody}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help and attention!

Comment: Can you give an "algorithm" or recipe for how to compress citations? What do you do with multiple authors, do you ignore "a" and "the" in titles, can there be such a thing as a label that is too long, do you want this for all or only some works, how can you make sure these labels are unique? If you only have some special sources that need this, try `shorthand`.

Comment: @moewe This is for just some books that have their own lives over conventions. The `shorthand` actually did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can stand doing the work manually, just put the required short form into the `shorthand` field.

The standard `verbose`-like styles and `biblatex-chicago`'s `note` style even have a function to give full citation with a "hereafter cited as " and then  in subsequent citations.